# Migrating Spring boot from 1.5 to 2.1.5 with old Spring rabbit 1.7.9 causing below exception

Tags: spring-amqp

spring boot 2.1.5
spring-rabbit 1.7.9
spring-amqp 1.7.9

Migrating Spring boot from 1.5 to 2.1.5 with old Spring rabbit 1.7.9 causing below exception while deploying:

```
java.net.URLClassLoader@763d9750
]


at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getDeclaredMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:507) ~[spring-core-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.doWithMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:404) ~[spring-core-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.doWithMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:389) ~[spring-core-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.determineCandidateConstructors(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:248) ~[spring-beans-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    ... 41 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/rabbitmq/client/QueueingConsumer
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_172]
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2701) ~[na:1.8.0_172]
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Class.java:1975) ~[na:1.8.0_172]
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getDeclaredMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:489) ~[spring-core-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    ... 44 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.rabbitmq.client.QueueingConsumer
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1333) ~[catalina.jar:8.0.39]
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1167) ~[catalina.jar:8.0.39]
    ... 48 common frames omitted

IF I exclude amqp-client from spring-rabbit, 
<exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.amqp</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-amqp</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.rabbitmq</groupId>
                    <artifactId>amqp-client</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
```

and add amqp-client dependency directly to use older version,

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>com.rabbitmq</groupId>
            <artifactId>amqp-client</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.3</version>
        </dependency>
```

throws below exception while deploying,
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/rabbitmq/client/impl/MicrometerMetricsCollector
which is part of amqp-client 5.4.3

Also, tried removing spring-rabbit and amqp 1.7.9 version to use default rabbitMQ 2.1.6 version with spring boot upgrade, still it fails for setCorrelationId method not found

### Question

Is It possible to use Spring boot 2.1.5 (which uses Spring 5.1.7) and spring-rabbit/amqp 1.7.9 version?

I cannot update spring-rabbit/amqp version as we are using custom jars 
managed from team which is managing queues and these custom jars are 
using 1.7.9 version.
so if we use new spring-rabbit/amqp version, while sending the message it 
fails for setCorrelationId method not found

Answer (score 0):

No; 1.7.9 cannot be used with boot 2.1; 2.1.x is compatible with Boot 2.1.x.

The current Boot 2.1.x version is 2.1.10 which uses Spring AMQP 2.1.12.

The correlation id was transitioned from `byte[]` to `String` and went through a deprecation cycle to make it easier for people going from 1.7.x->2.0.x->2.1.x.

The old version was deprecated in 1.7.x, transitioned in 2.0.x and removed in 2.1.x so jumping directly from 1.7.x to 2.1.x is more difficult.

But, even then, it just means changing the type from a `byte[]` to a `String`.